# After Copying ASP.NET MVC application to second, project cannot find existing nuget packages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I can't create an MVCE per se here, but to create this problem, build an MVC 5 application in Visual Studio with boilerplate nuget packages. Now move the project to a different computer and load it in Visual Studio. For me when I do this, Visual studio loses the boilerplate packages. These include Owen and Antlr and all of the standard stuff.

**They are correctly referenced in the packages.config and they exist in the packages directory.** I even tried deleting packages folder and rebuilding. It recreated the packages, but the project still complains that they can't be found. Even when I cloak the project in TFS and get it again this happens.

My instinct is to manually reset the references on the project, but the last time I did that it confused the hell out of Nuget. How can I fix this? What could I possibly be doing wrong? This doesn't happen with other types of projects.

***UPDATES:***

I manually added all of the missing references to my project. It changed the projects slightly.  Each reference was changed from:

```
<Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime">
  <HintPath>packages\Antlr.3.5.0.2\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

to:

```
<Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.5.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.5.0.2\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

The folder structure the same with the copied solution. I didn't change any of that. My packages folder is still a sibling with both my project (.csproj) and my solution (.sln) files. I don't know why it would want to go up a directory.

Also `<UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />` was added to the default property group.

The project is building with no errors now. All unit tests are passing. Does anyone know if I have shot myself in the foot here? Furthermore, am I going to have to do this every single time I get this project from version control? What is breaking here?

Comment: You did check and setup nuget restore I suppose?

Comment: How do I do that exactly?

Comment: I already tried restoring the packages. It downloaded everything appropriately, but still the project says they are broken references.